# why does my animation jiggle slightly in pygame?

Tags: python, animation, pygame

So I am in the process of coding a simple pong game but right now the ball sometimes has a small weird jiggle.  It doesn't mess up gameplay but the jiggle is certainly visible.  I monitored the speed of the ball and it seems to have a constant integer speed.  So why does the ball jitter slightly sometimes even though the speed of the ball remains the same?

Comment: Could you provide code?

Answer (score 1):

A code sample would be ideal but some of the problems you may be facing include:

- Pixel jitter because the ball needs to move at a speed that does not sync up with the frame rate of the game (so in 1 frame the ball move 3 pixels but in another it moves 2).
- Integer rounding. The position of the ball may be rounding to unexpected locations, so go over your code and check calculations of the balls movement.

It may be helpful to look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538991/smoother-motion-using-pygame.

However these are just speculation because I'm missing the source code.

Hope this helps :)